# CSS - (increasing) number as background images for CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve increasing numbers per article as background images in CSS aka this: https://snag.gy/NHVSpr.jpg

This one is  similar to another Stackoverflow here:
 Text as background images for CSS ( [Text as background images for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064945/text-as-background-images-for-css) )
 There is a JS FIDDLE over there too. The code for that one is:

```js
var $divs = $('.randbg'),
  alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

$divs.each(function ea() {
  var letter = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)].toUpperCase();

  $(this)
    .attr('data-content', letter)
    .html('<img src="http://placehold.it/75x75&number=' + letter + '"/>');
})
```

```css
.randbg {
  width: 7px;
  height: 75px;
}

.randbg:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randbg">What happens</div>
<div class="randbg">Why not</div>
<div class="randbg"></div>
<div class="randbg"></div>
```

My current code is:

```
<?php $i2=0; 
    foreach ($items2 as $item2) {
        if ($i2 < 4) {

            printf('<div class="right-now-box">');
            printf('<img src="%s" class="width-100">',$item2['image2']);
            printf('<a target="_blank" class="left-sidebar-news-text" href="%s">%s</a>', $item2['link2'], $item2['title2']);
            printf('</div>');

            $i2++;
         }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: My Current code give me this: 
https://snag.gy/nBf8CR.jpg . JSFIDDLE to mentioned stackoverflow: http://jsfiddle.net/vv058tho/1/

Comment: Make use of CSS counters and pseudo-elements such as `::before`!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : u really hate new members huh?

Comment: @Nancy Its not hate or love for members... Your question does not provide what you have tried so far...

Comment: Not at all, I try and help them understand how it should be done. If you want help then the onus is on you to provide as much information to those who have the willingness to offer their time.

Comment: When you give people -1 you severaly lower their chances to get something solved. I hope you understand this @RoryMcCrossan . 

Then its not about syntax. Its about either you tired of people writing not according to your philosophies how it should be written. Words as still Words. Or you have no recoglation how you first time here was. 

Stackoverflow wasn't over-zealous members who gives -1 to every thread they see is a little different then how themselves write. Rembember this.

Comment: I did not downvote you. I simply left the comment with guidance about how questions should be asked. I also don't appreciate your assumptions. People can downvote for whatever reason they like - and in this case they were more than justified as your question did not meet the basic rules of the site. If you cannot be bothered to familiarise yourself with a site's rules then only you have the responsibility for what happens as a result.

Comment: I actually upvoted this! `:O`

Comment: I received -3 in 2mintuts, Im sorry if I accidentally accuse you @RoryMcCrossan . That wasn't my intention at all, I just feel its good that People can give a chance to learn howto write and not get down-votes directly.

Comment: That sentiment I agree with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**CSS's counters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) and the pseudo-element `::before`:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: myCounter;         /* initialize a counter called myCounter */
}


.article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.article::before {                  /* for each .article add a ::before element */
  counter-increment: myCounter;     /* first increment the counter myCounter */
  content: counter(myCounter);      /* set the text of this ::before element to the value of counter */
  
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #00ffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
</div>
<div class="article">
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
</div>
<div class="article">
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
</div>
```

Comment: Ty so much @ibrahim <3 This is great for other people too I hope. Using a increasing number and not a random letter makes it more useful for div displayed by arrays.

Comment: Your welcome! Notice the `z-index` it's cruccial here!